# Brew: external commands with conflicting names

Tags: warnings, homebrew

Suddenly brew is giving me warnings:

```
Warning: You have external commands with conflicting names.

Found command `brew-cask-tests` in following places:
    /usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/cmd/brew-cask-tests.rb
    /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/brew-cask-tests.rb

Found command `brew-cask` in following places:
    /usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/cmd/brew-cask.rb
    /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd/brew-cask.rb
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to run the following command:

`brew update && brew uninstall --force brew-cask`

This seems to relate to a recent change to the cask package:
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/releases/tag/v0.60.0

> "NOTE This is the final release of Homebrew-cask. As of this release, it is no longer necessary to brew install brew-cask.
>
> `brew tap caskroom/cask` will install brew-cask as a Homebrew external command, and `brew update` will keep it up-to-date.
>
> You can `brew update && brew uninstall --force brew-cask` to clean up."